# Blobstore Python API のチュートリアルがうまくいかない

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/blobstore?hl=ja

上記のチュートリアルをやっているのですが、うまくいきません。
ソースコードは変更なしでそのままです。

```
from google.appengine.api import users
from google.appengine.ext import blobstore
from google.appengine.ext import ndb
from google.appengine.ext.webapp import blobstore_handlers
import webapp2

# This datastore model keeps track of which users uploaded which photos.
class UserPhoto(ndb.Model):
    user = ndb.StringProperty()
    blob_key = ndb.BlobKeyProperty()

class PhotoUploadFormHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        upload_url = blobstore.create_upload_url('/upload_photo')
        # To upload files to the blobstore, the request method must be "POST"
        # and enctype must be set to "multipart/form-data".
        self.response.out.write("""
<html><body>
<form action="{0}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  Upload File: <input type="file" name="file"><br>
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
</body></html>""".format(upload_url))

class PhotoUploadHandler(blobstore_handlers.BlobstoreUploadHandler):
    def post(self):
        upload = self.get_uploads()[0]
        user_photo = UserPhoto(
            user=users.get_current_user().user_id(),
            blob_key=upload.key())
        user_photo.put()

        self.redirect('/view_photo/%s' % upload.key())

class ViewPhotoHandler(blobstore_handlers.BlobstoreDownloadHandler):
    def get(self, photo_key):
        if not blobstore.get(photo_key):
            self.error(404)
        else:
            self.send_blob(photo_key)

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
    ('/', PhotoUploadFormHandler),
    ('/upload_photo', PhotoUploadHandler),
    ('/view_photo/([^/]+)?', ViewPhotoHandler),
], debug=True)
```

デプロイして実行すると、フォームのHTMLは表示されるのですが（create_upload_urlでのURLの取得もうまくいっている）、ファイルを選択してsubmitすると、403エラーが返ってきてしまいます。

なぜでしょうか？
１つチュートリアルと違う部分は、App EngineにIP制限をしていますが、関係なさそうです。（一応127.0.0.1やApp Engine自体のIPも許可してみたのですが変わらずでした）

Answer (score 0):

> １つチュートリアルと違う部分は、App EngineにIP制限をしていますが、関係なさそうです。（一応127.0.0.1やApp Engine自体のIPも許可してみたのですが変わらずでした）

関係なさそうと書いておきながら、こちらが原因でした。

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/creating-firewalls?hl=ja
上記に記載のIPを許可することで解決しました。